# add/remove text multiple line for javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-apollo

I have the multiple line string which need to remove/add 
here's the data that I would like to edit

```
  data{
      id
      date
      ***progress{
        update
        progressStatus
      }***
      events {
        id
        time
      }
    }
```

my point is how do I remove

```
progress{
            update
            progressStatus
          }
```

I had tried 'replace', 'assign' to remove it as below but not working

```
  const test = data.replace(progress, '');
```

Thank you.

Comment: Add the code you've tried to your question, please, as a [mcve].

Comment: @ppppp if you want to delete object properties then use delete data.progress;

Comment: The special characters are causing an issue. Regex might be the solution for your problem.

Comment: It looks like graphql query, am I right ?

Comment: @PatrickFerreira yes

Answer (score 1):

Here's the logic, I'm considering that you want to remove the "progress" which has an open curly bracket('{') and a closing curly bracket('}'):

```js
var data = `data{
      id
      date
      ***progress{
        update
        progressStatus
      }***
      events {
        id
        time
      }
    }`;
function _remove(data, key) {
  var s = data.indexOf(key);
  var e = ((s) => {
    for(var i=s; i<data.length; i++){
      if(data[i] == "}")
        return i;
    }
  })(s + key.length);
  console.log(data.replace(data.substr(s, e-s+1), ""));
}
_remove(data, 'progress');
```

Can be done with regex as well!

Answer (score 0):

What is **I have the multiple line** ? The query of grapqh will return an object, why still a multiple string ?

In your case (the query data is a string), try:

```js
const data = ` data{
      id
      date
      progress{
        update
        progressStatus
      }
      events {
        id
        time
      }
    }`
const newData = data.replace(`progress{
        update
        progressStatus
      }`, '')
console.log(newData)
```

If you want to delete one key in object, try this:

```
delete data.progress;

// or,
delete data['progress'];

// or,
const prop = "progress";
delete data[prop];
```

Demo:

```js
const data = {
       progress: {
          x: "x"
       },
       events: {
          id: 1
       }
    }

delete data.progress
console.log(data)
```

Comment: The input is not a JSON it's a string. So this would not work.

Comment: **I have the multiple line string**  he has a string, not an object

Answer (score 0):

You could try with a regexep

[image]

```js
const regex = /progress{[^}]+}\s+/gm;
const str = `data{
      id
      date
      progress{
        update
        progressStatus
      }
      events {
        id
        time
      }
    }`;
const subst = ``;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```